# Problema de complejidad computacional en java con recursividad

Tags: java, complejidad

Tengo esta tarea donde tengo que indicar y justificar la función de complejidad y el orden de complejidad del algoritmo del siguiente método recursivo que analiza la paridad de un número n.

```
public static boolean esPar(int n) {
    if (n == 0) {
    return true;
    }
    return !esPar(n−1);
    }
```

Y escrbir otro método que haga exactamente lo mismo que el método esPar(int n) pero con
una complejidad mejor. Justificando el mismo con mis palabras y/o lenguaje matemático.
Tengo mis dudas de como se, porque no me quedó muy claro el tema visto en clase. Puse que el Orden de complejidad era `O(1)` pero me dijo el profesor que estaba mal.

Answer (score 3):

Para conocer el orden de complejidad de la función  calcularemos el costo de la función. Vamos a tomar el costo en base al  número de veces que tiene que entrar en recursividad antes de obtener el resultado.

Sea *C(n)* el costo de calcular la paridad  de *n* utilizando la función *EsPar(n)*.  Para ello, vamos a darle algunos valores a *n*.

```
1) n=0 -> C(0) = 0
2) n=1 -> C(1) = 1 + C(0) =>  C(1) = 1 + 0 => C(1) = 1
3) n=2 -> C(2) = 1 + C(1)
4) n+1 -> C(n+1) = 1 + C(n)
```

Por 4 se observa que el costo es una  funcion lineal  puesto crece proporcionalmente al incremento  de *n*:

```
C(n+1) = 1 + C(n) // por 4
       = 1  + n   // por 1 y 2
       = n  +  1   // por algebra
```

Por lo tanto es costo de la función es lineal  correspondiendole un orden de complejidad **O(n)**.

Veamos una la función *esPar2* para calcular la paridad de *n*:

```
public static boolean esPar2(int n) {
    return (n%2)==0;
}
```

Está función toma el mismo tiempo para cualquier *n*, es decir, tiene un costo constante y por lo tanto un orden de complejidad O(1).

En resumen:

```
EsPar(n) -> O(n)
EsPar2(n) -> O(1)
```

Espero que hayas entendido lo que el orden de complejidad y que respondas la tarea con tus  propias palabras porque  te pueden preguntar algo que no he puesto.